# Dynamically set ViewPager height

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am trying to put a `ViewPager` with different fragments with different heights. I know that `wrap_content` is not working with `ViewPager` so I am trying to set pager height dinamically.
I am setting the pager height in a page listener:

```
...
        indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int selected) {
                final View view = fragments[selected].getView();
                if (view != null) {
                    pager.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, view
                                    .getMeasuredHeight()));

                }

            }
```

Unfortunately it is not working because the value returned by `getMeasuredHeight()` on `Fragment` is wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
    ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = mViewPager.getViewTreeObserver();
    viewTreeObserver
            .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    int viewPagerWidth = mViewPager.getWidth();
                    float viewPagerHeight = (float) (viewPagerWidth * FEATURED_IMAGE_RATIO);

                    layoutParams.width = viewPagerWidth;
                    layoutParams.height = (int) viewPagerHeight;

                    mViewPager.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    mViewPager.getViewTreeObserver()
                            .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }
            });
```

I call it in onResume();

Comment: But OnGlobalLayoutListener is not called. Why?

Comment: Are you sure? Did you log it and made sure it is not?

Comment: What is the FEATURED_IMAGE_RATIO?? I'am trying to use it on a fragmentpageradapter

Comment: My ViewPager displays just the image. I know image ratios upfront so FEATURED_IMAGE_RATIO is just a constant value to calculate the height of the ViewPager.

Comment: @czaku I have a similar problem but a bit different, kindly check from http://stackoverflow.com/q/38342500/2595059

Answer (score 1):

Try to set its parameters in onLayout() of the viewpager

Comment: so are you suggesting to extend the viewPager? The problem is that the pager should have the height of the displayed fragment, so I don't understand how this could be solved in onLayout().