# How to dynamically set the height of viewpager in android

Tags: android

I have read and tried a lot of works on the way to set the view pager to obtain a dynamic height buh to no avail. After setting the below, the screen was divided half and the list of data was scrolling from the middle of the screen.

**CustomPager**

```
public class CustomPager extends ViewPager {

private View mCurrentView;

public CustomPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if (mCurrentView == null) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        return;
    }
    int height = 0;
    mCurrentView.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    int h = mCurrentView.getMeasuredHeight();
    if (h > height) height = h;
    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

public void measureCurrentView(View currentView) {
    mCurrentView = currentView;
    requestLayout();
}

public int measureFragment(View view) {
    if (view == null)
        return 0;

    view.measure(0, 0);
    return view.getMeasuredHeight();
}
}
```

**CustomScrollView**

```
 public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new YScrollDetector());
    setFadingEdgeLength(0);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
            && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
}

// Return false if we're scrolling in the x direction
class YScrollDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                            float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return (Math.abs(distanceY) > Math.abs(distanceX));
    }
}
}
```

**HomePage**

```
 public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite,
        R.drawable.ic_tab_call,
        R.drawable.ic_tab_contacts
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_view_icon_text_tabs);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);



   tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    setupTabIcons();
}

private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);

    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).select();

}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new One(), "One");
    adapter.addFrag(new Two(), "Two");
    adapter.addFrag(new Three(), "Three");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    private int mCurrentPosition = -1;


    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }



    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
        if (position != mCurrentPosition) {
            Fragment fragment = (Fragment) object;
            CustomPager pager = (CustomPager) container;
            if (fragment != null && fragment.getView() != null) {
                mCurrentPosition = position;
                pager.measureCurrentView(fragment.getView());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

}


}
```

**FRAGMENT ONE**

```
       <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lists"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        >
    </ListView>



</FrameLayout>
```

Is there a way to make the above make the viewPager dynamic in height. I am grateful. Thanks

Comment: Dynamic in the sense ?? describe the problem correctly one line descriptions are not enough..!!

Comment: @jankigadhiya I am trying to put a ViewPager with different fragments with different heights. I know that wrap_content is not working with ViewPager so I am trying to set pager height dynamically. However using the `Custompager class` couldn't solve it

Comment: @jankigadhiya I hope you now understand.